# Class Extends a Trait With/Without Parentheses

Tags: scala

Looking at this code from [Scala in Depth](http://www.manning.com/suereth/)...

```
scala> trait Foo {
     |  def someMethod(): Int = 5
     | }
defined trait Foo

scala> class Main() extends Foo {
     |   }
defined class Main
```

Then, I created a new `Main` (without the parentheses).

```
scala> class Main extends Foo {}
defined class Main
```

What is the meaning the parentheses in `class Main()`? How about **without** parentheses?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the same.  If you leave the parentheses off it's the same as empty parentheses.

```
class A()
new A()
new A

class B
new B()
new B
```

It's all the same.

Answer (score 5):

5.3 of the spec:

> If no formal parameter sections are given, an empty parameter section
>   () is assumed.

This is different from methods, which can be parameterless.

When you write

```
class A
```

you are really writing

```
class A()
```

Moreover,

```
scala> class A(implicit i: Int)
defined class A

scala> new A
<console>:9: error: could not find implicit value for parameter i: Int
              new A
              ^

scala> new A()(1)
res1: A = A@32185a4a

scala> new A(1)
<console>:9: error: too many arguments for constructor A: ()(implicit i: Int)A
              new A(1)
              ^
```

Answer (score 2):

In parentheses after the class name you have arguments of the primary constructor. In this case there are no arguments, so you can leave the parentheses out.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to 'what is idiomatic' seems to actually depend on the function in question. According to [Lift in Action](http://timperrett.com/book.html)'s Appendix A:

> "It is typically idiomatic within Scala to give methods that have zero arguments no trailing parenthesis if the function is referentially transparent."

Thus, `Thing.foo`, which has no side-effects (it's just retrieving a value), is fine. If `foo` has a side effect, it is idiomatic to write `foo()` so that readers know something else is going on. Either way, Scala assumes the parenthesis and does not *make* you write them.