# Instantiate a Class - With or Without Parens?

Tags: scala

```
scala> class A { ... }
defined class A
```

`A` can be instantiated with or without parentheses:

```
scala> val a = new A
a: A = A@4a27b5cd

scala> val aaa = new A()
aaa: A = A@68aa419e
```

Which form is (more) idiomatic?

Should the parentheses be included since, as I understand, creating an object is a `side effect`, similarly to a [0-arity argument's style](http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/method-invocation.html)?

Comment: Why the downvote? I searched for answers before posting. If it's already been answered, please let me know.

Comment: If you define it without a constructor parameter list, instantiate it that way.

Comment: This is just style, doesn't make much of a difference. you're probably better asking this at http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I can't think of any sense in which it's reasonable to consider instantiation to be a side effect. That would imply that pretty much every expression is side-effecting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wrote a similar answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/20664517/1296806

It's especially relevant that constructors are not like methods with respect to parens.

A constructor always has a non-implicit parameter list.  If you omit it in the definition, then it is supplied.

`new A` is idiomatic. (If there's a need to rationalize it, consider the instance as a result.  If instantiation is a side effect, nothing non-primitive could be pure.)

`new A().a` requires the parens, so they are useful syntactically.

You must supply parens if an implicit follows; see the link.

Comment: Thanks, @som-snytt. Sorry I forgot to upvote your other, helpful answer.